# processing huge csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Lets assume I have a huge csv (about 10Gb) file as below:

```
name1,150
name2,89
name3,50
```

Now i want to get the sum of all 2nd columns and I write code in 2 ways.

```
import csv
fp=open("d:\\testdata.csv")

def total(pointer):
reader=csv.reader(pointer)
 for i in reader:
     yield (i[1])
sum=0
for t in total(fp):
 sum+=int(t)
print(sum)
```

and

```
import csv
fp=open("d:\\testdata.csv")
reader=csv.reader(fp)
sum=0
for i in reader:
  sum+=int(i[1])
print(sum)
```

Which method is better ? Is there any advantage with the first one using generator ? If not, in case using generator benefits us ?

Comment: In your particular example, there is no advantage to using a generator other than making your code longer and more convoluted

Comment: `csv.reader` is already a generator, so the first code is just wrapping a generator in a generator and is overall slower and more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Ohh got it..thank you @m

Comment: I think you need some threads.

Comment: in that case , an example in this also wrapping generator inside generator as readline is a generator ?

https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2014/01/27/python-201-an-intro-to-generators/

Comment: @MarkTolonen Is `reader` really a generator? DictReader isn't and the regular reader is implemented in C and doesn't match `types.GeneratorType`

Comment: That example specifically shows essentially equivalent code without using a generator. A generator is more useful if you want to more clearly write code that, say, maintains some state internal to the generator. If you're just reading a file, the stream or line iterator already tracks the 'position in file' state so there's not much to be gained by putting a generator around it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's not going to matter much. We're talking about nanoseconds of CPU optimization here on a workload that is likely going to be I/O bound.

Let's take a step back. Is this a one-off operation? Is your data size truly 10 GB? If so, stop; you're done. Taking the time to post on Stack Overflow is going to be the dominant cost of your code. :-)

If not -- that is, you're going to be doing this repeatedly, on datasets that are possibly orders of magnitude larger -- you'll probably want to focus on fixing the I/O issue. You may need to split the data across multiple disks and attack it using multiple threads. This is a [typical MapReduce pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce). [Apache Presto](https://prestodb.io/overview.html) is a commonly used engine to divide-and-conquer CSV files.

If, like me, you're too lazy to figure out how to set Presto up, take a look at a hosted solution like [Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/) (which is based on Presto) or [Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data). Both have Python SDKs.

(Full disclosure: I'm a Solutions Architect with AWS, but opinions here are my own.)