# Parsing huge csv with mixed headers

Tags: python

There is a huge csv file 140GB with a header that looks like

```
1,22-05-16T17:36:54.485000000,,,Trace1(DBM),-74.38,-45.82,...
1,22-05-16T17:36:54.485000000,,,Trace2(DBM),-84.22,-65.32,...
1,22-05-16T17:36:54.485000000,,,Trace3(DBM),-75.18,-77.12,...
2,22-05-16T17:36:55.002000000,,,Trace1(DBM),-81.36,79.72,...
```

What I want for an output is

```
#Trace1
array1[0,:] = [-74.38, -81.36 etc
array1[1,:] = [-45.82, -79.72, etc
#Trace2
array2[0,:] = [-84.22,  etc
array2[1,:] = [-65.32, etc
#Trace3
array3[0,:] = [-75.18, etc
array3[1,:] = [-77.12, etc
```

Each subarray,`array1[N,M]` will have M = 2001 points and N = Huge number.

I have looked for solutions like

[processing huge csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47254173/processing-huge-csv-file)

Current code, I am experimenting with this

```py
def process_file(directory_to_write, filename_date_str, time_intervals, frequency_array, number_points):
    logger.info(frequency_array.ghz)
    logger.info(number_points)
    for i in range(time_intervals):
        file_to_open = os.path.join(directory_to_write, filename_date_str[i])
        logger.info(file_to_open)
        with open(file_to_open, mode='r', encoding='UTF-8', errors='ignore') as csvfile:
            line_number: int = 0
            for line in csvfile:
                line_number += 1
                line_to_validate = line.strip()
                if not line_to_validate:
                    continue
                elif line_number > 2:
                    break
                else:
                    custom_parser(line_to_validate)
                    logger.info(str(line_number))
        file_CSV = open(file_to_open)
        data_CSV = csv.reader(file_CSV)
        list_CSV = list(data_CSV)
        for row in list_CSV:
            print(row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5])
```

Using the code is really slow with the 'if' statement but it is doable.

Question is how do improve the efficiency of parsing these monster files?

Is it possible to just brute force 'chop' off the first few columns before processing line by line?